# How to restrict access to some restlet resources

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, restlet, restlet-2.0

I'm trying to figuring out what is the best way to restrict access to some resources using the restlet framework.
In my case, I have a POJO object

```
public class User
{
    private Integer id;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean adminPrivileges;
}
```

So, what I'm trying to do is the following: if the resource requested by the client is under

- `/normal-user`, it is requested that the `User` is authenticated and that he is enabled (ie `enabled=true`)
- `/admin-user`, it is requested that the `User` is authenticated, that he is enabled and has admin privileges (ie `enabled=true` and `adminPrivileges=true`)
- otherwise, no authentication is required

What is the best way to accomplish this goal? Note that I don't want to restrict the access to some files or directories, but only to specific resources (ie instances of `ServerResource`).
Can I achieve it only using restlet APIs? Or do I have to implement some kind of servlet `Filter`? I've read something on the `Guard` class used by restlet, as far as I understand it's only used to restrict access to specific directories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes guards are the way with Restlet to apply security on resources. They allow to check the authentication (Verifier) and load corresponding roles (Enroler) if the authentication is successful.

Guards are configured when defining your routing in your Reslet application class and must be defined in front of resources or routers you santé to protect...

Hope it helps you.
Thierry